# Neo4j - Can't load all fields from CSV

Tags: neo4j

This is my load command:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/Users/levi/data/woka-data/atom_description.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Description {language: row.content.language, value: row.content.value, woka_id: row.woka_id});
```

This are the first couple rows in my CSV file (first line is the header):
content.language,content.value,woka_id

```
"eng","This handbook is the first of its kind to discuss infection control guidelines that directly relate to surgical environments. It is particularly useful to nurses who need to meet OSHA and JCAHO requirements for practice in perioperative, PACU, ambulatory, and endoscopy settings. Procedure guidelines are concisely described and followed by rationales referenced to AORN standards, CDC guidelines, and other resources.","97800000003300000000"
"eng","Practitioners and academics dealing with the Middle East can turn to the Yearbook of Islamic and Middle Eastern Law for an instant source of information on the developments over an entire year in the region. The Yearbook covers Islamic and non-Islamic legal subjects, including the laws themselves, of some twenty Arab and other Islamic countries. The publication's practical features include: <br>- articles on current topics, <br>-country surveys reflecting important new legislation and amendments to existing legislation per country, <br>- the text of a selection of documents and important court cases, <br>- a Notes and News section, and<br>- book reviews. <br>","97800000222400000000"
```

This is what was effectively loaded in the db:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (n: Description) return (n) limit 10;                                              

+------------------------------------------------+
| n                                              |
+------------------------------------------------+
| Node[26293467]{woka_id:"97800000003300000000"} |
| Node[26293468]{woka_id:"97800000222400000000"} |
| Node[26293469]{woka_id:"97800000255240000000"} |
| Node[26293470]{woka_id:"97800002099930000000"} |
| Node[26293471]{woka_id:"97800002966650000000"} |
| Node[26293472]{woka_id:"97800010161180000000"} |
| Node[26293473]{woka_id:"97800010161320000000"} |
| Node[26293474]{woka_id:"97800010161560000000"} |
| Node[26293475]{woka_id:"97800010162170000000"} |
| Node[26293476]{woka_id:"97800010162310000000"} |
+------------------------------------------------+
10 rows
27 ms
```

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not have dots in the csv's header field. Replace them e.g. by underscore, both in the header line and in the `LOAD CSV` command.

Comment: Alternativiely you can try to stick with the dots and use backticks to quote the fieldnames: `CREATE (:Description {language: row.\`content.language\`,...`

Comment: Or you can skip the header line and use the column number:

WITH row SKIP 1 
CREATE (:Description {language: row[0], value: row[1], woka_id: row[2]});

Comment: It worked. I will avoid dots in the field names in the future.